# tcl expect regular expression not working?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to expect for different type of network devices but I can't make a more complex regular expression work.

For Cisco devices I have :

```
expect {"*>"}
```

The * works fine

But for Fortinet devices I want to do this

```
expect {"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]+[#]"}
```

and it doesn't work. I checked on a REGEX "checker" to make sure the expression is right and it seems to work. So Basically, I want to filter for lines that start with "NAME_OF_DEVICE #" because this is how Fortinet shell is when you first connect to it

Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: A tip: while developing an expect script, add `exp_internal 1`  near the top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html): "Regexp-style patterns follow the syntax defined by Tcl's regexp (short for "regular expression") command. regexp patterns are introduced with the flag -re."

Your example:

`expect -re {^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]+#} ...`

Comment: Since using a dash in the middle of a character class defines a character range, I would additionally suggest to put the dash either at the beginning or a the end of your pattern (in case you want to literally match a dash), e.g. `{^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.\s]+#}`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but now both my Cisco and Fortinet expect don't work.

Comment: In your examples you're double quoting your expressions. Maybe that's tripping you up. You should use: `expect -re {^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]+#}` (note: no quotes), or if you really want to use quotes, `expect {-re "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]+#"}` (-re inside the braces). Your Cisco expression isn't a valid regexp, so don't use the -re switch there.